# return statement covered by mutex lock?

Tags: c++, locking, mutex, raii

I have some code that returns a copy the current instance of an object.

```
SomeObj getInstance() {
    std::lock_guard lock(m_mutex);
    return m_obj
}
```

`m_obj` can change in another thread and its copy-constructor / assignment operator are not atomic.
When `return m_obj` is copying the object, is the lock still held? Or do I need to do something like:

```
SomeObj getInstance() {
    SomeObj ret;
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(m_mutex);
        ret = m_obj;
    }
    return ret;
}
```